# Install ArcGIS Desktop ArcMap for a single user on Windows 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, installation

I want to install ArcMap 10.8.1 not for all users of a Laptop but only for a single user. Is there a way to do so on Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried doing the install?  I'm pretty sure that one of the dialogs gets you to choose between All Users and a single user.

Comment: @PolyGeo I doubt if it's only available when installing Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.  ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) only allows Per-Machine installation while ArcGIS Pro allows Per-Machine and Per-User installations.

The answer can be inferred through Esri's documentation.  Reading through [Installing ArcGIS Desktop on your computer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/installation-guide/installing-on-your-computer.htm), there is no mention of either per-machine or per-user installation, but the screenshots only show a per-machine installation.  *It isn't explicit, but the inference is accurate.*  Reading through [Install ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/get-started/install-and-sign-in-to-arcgis-pro.htm), per-machine and per-user installations are explicitly mentioned.

> You can make either a per-machine installation (the default) or a
> per-user installation of ArcGIS Pro. A per-machine installation allows
> any user to run ArcGIS Pro on the computer on which it is installed. A
> per-user installation allows only the user who installs it to run the
> application.

Regardless of what the documentation states, what really matters is how the installer is configured because that is reality regardless of what a web page says.  One can use PowerShell and WindowsInstaller COM to get a definitely answer.

```
PS C:\> $MsiPackages = @() # Array of paths to Pro and ArcMap installers
PS C:\> foreach ($MsiPath in $MsiPackages) {
>>     $MsiDb = (New-Object -ComObject "WindowsInstaller.Installer").OpenDatabase($MsiPath, 0)
>>     $MsiSql = @(
>>        "SELECT Property, Value FROM Property WHERE"
>>        "Property = 'ProductName' OR"
>>        "Property = 'ProductVersion' OR"
>>        "Property = 'ALLUSERS'"
>>     ) -join " "
>>     $MsiDbView = $MsiDb.OpenView($MsiSql)
>>     $MsiDbView.Execute()
>>     while ($MsiRecord = $MsiDbView.Fetch()) {
>>         "$($MsiRecord.StringData(1)), $($MsiRecord.StringData(2))"
>>     }
>>     ""
>> }
>>
ALLUSERS, 1
ProductName, ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2
ProductVersion, 10.8.28388

ProductName, ArcGIS Pro
ProductVersion, 2.9.32739
ALLUSERS, 2
```

According to [ALLUSERS property - Win32 apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/allusers):

> - An ALLUSERS property value of 1 specifies the per-machine installation context.
> - The value ALLUSERS=2 enables the system to reset the value of ALLUSERS, and the installation context, dependent upon the user's
>   privileges and the version of Windows.

So, according to the Windows Installers themselves, ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) can only be installed Per-Machine while ArcGIS Pro can be either Per-Machine or Per-User.

Comment: and there is no way to call the MSI with ALLUSERS=2 or ALLUSERS=0 for ArcMAP, right .... like overriding this setting at installtion?

Comment: @Riccardo, I don't believe so.  If you read over the ALLUSERS property documentation, the property value can only be changed at runtime if the value is set to 2 initially.  Even if there was a way to force a change from `1` to `""`, the installer would either fail at some point or the installation would be corrupt since the MSI was never compiled in the first place to support per-user installation.